# How do I split a single column dataframe into multiple columns by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've browsed a few answers but haven't found the exact thing i'm looking for yet.

I have a pandas dataframe with a single column structured as follows (example)

```
0 alex
1 7 
2 female
3 nora
4 3
5 female 
...
999 fred 
1000 15 
1001 male
```

i want to split that single column into 3 columns holding name, age, and gender. to look something like this:

```
  name  age  gender
0 alex  7    female
1 nora  3    female
...
100 fred 15  male
```

is there a way to do this? i was thinking about using the index but not sure how to actually do it

Comment: where are these values for the three columns coming from?

Comment: it's an example on the data from splitting the orignal column

Comment: I should have been more explicit. Those values are not in the question, how i'll be able to provide in the answer?

Comment: there is no alex, nora, fed in your example inut column, so how are we meant to conjure them out of thin air?

Comment: and they always follow that same order?

Comment: yes, it's always like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most efficient solution perhaps, but you can use `pd.concat()` and put them all next to each other, if they're always in order:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':['alex',7,'female','nora',3,'female','fred',15,'male']})
df2 = pd.concat([df[(df.index + x) % 3 == 0].reset_index(drop=True) for x in range(3)],axis=1)
df2.columns = ["name", "gender", "age"]
```

Returns:

```
name    gender  age
0   alex    female  7
1   nora    female  3
2   fred    male    15
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming "0" is your column name:

```
list_a = list(df[0])
a  = np.array(list_a).reshape(-1, 3).tolist()
df2= pd.DataFrame(a,columns = ["name", "age","gender"])
```

Comment: I like this better than what I came up with. Great idea! I tested it and found you don't even need to go through the lists so you can make this one line: `df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.Value).reshape(-1,3),columns=["name", "gender", "age"])`

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["alex", 7, "female", "nora", 3, "female", "fred", 15, "male"])

people = range(len(df) // 3)
attributes = ["name", "age", "gender"]

multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([people, attributes])

df.set_index(multi_index).unstack(level=1).droplevel(level=0, axis=1).reindex(columns=attributes)
```

Output:

```
   name age  gender
0  alex   7  female
1  nora   3  female
2  fred  15    male
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# step through the DF and get values for name, age and gender as series
# each starts from 0, 1 and 3

name=df['Value'][::3].values
age=df['Value'][1::3].values
gender=df['Value'][2::3].values

# create a DF based on the values
out=pd.DataFrame({'name': name,
             'age' : age,
            'gender': gender})
out
```

```
    name    age  gender
0   alex    7    female
1   nora    3    female
2   fred    15   male
```